# pprint in Allegro CL

Tags: common-lisp, pprint, allegro-cl

I'm attempting to write a program in Common Lisp that dynamically creates other lisp files. Common Lisp's `print` function seems very useful for this purpose. Unfortunately, the function outputs data on a single line. For example (just printing to standard output):

```
(print '(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c)))
>> (let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c))
```

The generated lisp files need to be human readable and thus shouldn't minimize whitespace. It seems that the `pprint` function is the solution to my problem. Since [pprint sets `*pretty-print*` to true](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_pre.htm), the function should print on multiple lines. In other words:

```
(pprint '(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c)))
>>  (let ((a 1)
>>        (b 2)
>>        (c 3))
>>    (+ a b c))
```

However, in Allegro CL, pprint seems to behave in an identical manner to print. Output is only on a single line. Is there a way to cause the function to print s-expressions in a "pretty" way? Are there any other globals that need to be set before the function prints correctly? Is there an alternative function/macro that I'm looking for? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What're [print-miser-width](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_mis.htm#STprint-miser-widthST) and [print-right-margin](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_rig.htm)set to?  Your form isn't all that big;  maybe it's not too big to fit on a single line, as far as the printer's concerned.  You *could* set up a custom print dispatch table for code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the accept; I guess the answer was useful. :) Out of curiosity¸which route did you end up taking? Was playing with *print-right-margin* enough, or did you write some custom functions with the pretty printer?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In the end, playing with `*print-right-margin*` wasn't enough. I eventually defined pprint functions for the set of constructs I needed to output (in a similar way to the `pprint-let` function from [22.2.2 Examples of using the Pretty Printer](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_bb.htm). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pretty printer is controlled by more than just *print-pretty*.  E.g., look at the interaction with [*print-right-margin*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_rig.htm) in SBCL (under SLIME):

```
CL-USER> (pprint '(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c)))

(LET ((A 1) (B 2) (C 3))
  (+ A B C))
; No value
CL-USER> (let ((*print-right-margin* 10))
           (pprint '(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c))))

(LET ((A
       1)
      (B
       2)
      (C
       3))
  (+ A B
     C))
; No value
CL-USER> (let ((*print-right-margin* 20))
           (pprint '(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (+ a b c))))

(LET ((A 1)
      (B 2)
      (C 3))
  (+ A B C))
; No value
```

You might be able to get satisfactory results just by setting that variable, but in general you'll want to have a look at [22.2 The Lisp Pretty Printer](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_b.htm).  Pretty printing functions have lots of places for optional newlines and the like, and where they get put depends on a number of things (like *print-right-margin* and *print-miser-width*).  There are some examples of using the pretty printer to format Lisp source code in [22.2.2 Examples of using the Pretty Printer](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_bb.htm).  There's too much to quote it all, but it shows how the following pretty printing code can produce all these outputs, depending on context:

```
(defun simple-pprint-defun (*standard-output* list)
  (pprint-logical-block (*standard-output* list :prefix "(" :suffix ")")
    (write (first list))
    (write-char #\Space)
    (pprint-newline :miser)
    (pprint-indent :current 0)
    (write (second list))
    (write-char #\Space)
    (pprint-newline :fill)
    (write (third list))
    (pprint-indent :block 1)
    (write-char #\Space)
    (pprint-newline :linear)
    (write (fourth list))))
```

```
 (DEFUN PROD (X Y) 
   (* X Y))
```

```
(DEFUN PROD
       (X Y)
  (* X Y))
```

```
 (DEFUN
  PROD
  (X Y)
  (* X Y))
```

```
 ;;; (DEFUN PROD
 ;;;        (X Y)
 ;;;   (* X Y))
```